# Pandas Intersection after grouping based on common errors between each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

[image: Dataframe]

I want to find intersections based on `ID` that consistently have errors in all the `Run`.
So, all `ID`s are repeating in all `Run`s. I tried to group data by `Run` first, then as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014062/pandas-intersection-of-groups) similar question. I tried the code, but it doesn't return an intersection.

```
 filter=all_data_df.groupby('Run')['Error'].transform('nunique') == all_data_df['Error'].nunique()
 df = all_data_df.loc[filter]
```

The results is same dataframe I started with.
How can this be fixed?

I am expecting to obtain

[image]

Where only ID `234534` consistently has errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to keep only the `Id`*s* that have errors in [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) runs :

```
# Below, I'm using `df` instead of `all_data_df`

consistent_errors = df["Error"].eq("Yes").groupby(df["Id"]).transform("all")

out = df.loc[consistent_errors]
```

Comment: This works well. I am also interested to know why  [previous code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014062/pandas-intersection-of-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1)  isnt working as its for the given use-case

Comment: I'm not sure about that but maybe because you're treating the `Yes`/`No` errors, the same. Not to mention that the linked question is different than yours. Try masking the `No` values first : `filter_ = all_data_df.mask(all_data_df['Error'].eq('No')).groupby('Id')['Run'].transform('nunique') == df['Run'].nunique(); out = all_data_df.loc[filter_]`.

Comment: I was revisiting this today and one thing caught my eye, why in your example `...groupby(df["Id"])...` works but if we just use use Id `...groupby("Id")...` it doesnt work and I get key error. I even tried getting keys by running `df["Error"].eq("Yes").keys()` and got `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=30, step=1)`

Comment: Because in `df["Error"].eq("Yes").groupby(df["Id"])`, we use [`pd.Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html). So, you're getting a `KeyError` with `groupby("Id")` because here the series has no `"Id"` key/index.